# How to remove first closed paren and last open in a sentence using regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to get rid of false parens. This is example sentence:

```
s = "trees 1) whatever ( goor brc ) the content ( and bad now."
```

I need to remove only first `)` and last `(` from it.

My code doesn't work because I use illegal syntax. However, I some languages it would be good probably:

```
re.sub("(?<=^.*?)\)|(?<=.*)\(", "", s)
```

How to obey this?

**EDIT**

This regex probably matches first `)`: `(?:)\)`
This works on regex101 but with `s = re.sub("(?:\)){1}", "", s)` removes all `)`.

I found maybe not very elegant solution but works:

```
bos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer("\(", s)]
        bcs = [m.start() for m in re.finditer("\)", s)]
        if min(bcs) < min(bos):
            s = s[:min(bcs)] + s[(min(bcs)+1):]
        bos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer("\(", s)]
        bcs = [m.start() for m in re.finditer("\)", s)]
        if max(bos) > max(bcs):
            s = s[:max(bos)] + s[(max(bos)+1):]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this expression,

```
(\([^)]+\))|([()]+)
```

might work to some extent, not sure though.

#### Test with `re.sub`

```
import re

regex = r"(\([^)]+\))|([()]+)"

test_str = "trees 1) whatever ( goor brc ) the content ( and bad now. trees 1) whatever ( goor brc ) the content ( and bad now. trees 1) whatever ( goor brc ) the content ( and bad now. the content ( and bad now. the content ( and bad now.the content (((( and bad now. (((("

subst = "\\1"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)
result = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", result)
print (result)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJDrsw/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/bJDrsw/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

#### Failure

It would fail for [such samples](https://regex101.com/r/vdU6KP/1/).

Comment: It would make smiley face look surprised :-)